# Modify one component with another (HOC maybe?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have seen that some libraries such as "framer-motion" from react work using this syntax, for example to insert an animated H1: `<motion.h1>` which would translate to an h1 but with animations defined in the props of the component.

What I don't understand is how the "motion" component accesses that "h1" and then in the function it knows which component to render animated.

I need to create a component for example `<lazy.div>` that interprets a div with certain modifications that I am going to define.

What I need to know is how to use that syntax and not the typical

```
<Lazy><h1>Content<h1> </Lazy>
```

Would it also be possible to use this type of syntax to modify chain elements or add functions to those already modified components?

For example `<lazy.fullwidth.div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a function that function is an object. You can then add any properties to that object and a property itself can be another function.

So if you have a react component function you can make properties of it also be component functions.

Simple example:

```js
const Example = () => (<div>Example Main Component</div> );

Example.h1 = () => (<h1>Example.h1 component</h1>)

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Example />
    <Example.h1/>
  </div>  
  )

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much awesome bro! that helped me a lot now i understand but as i see, i would need to define each element in that object. Is there any way the component creates that for me? maybe not using example.h1 but using <example as="h1" /> so then the component takes that prop and return an <h1 /> so if i use any element in the "as" prop it would render it as a component?

Comment: You would handle `as` the same way you would any other props.

Comment: Ok nice thank you, as i see i can just use. var htmlVAR = props.as; return <htmlVAR /> and it will return an h1 for example? ty so much!